# GCC's decltype(auto) doesn't conform to the standard?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, auto, decltype

I tried compiling this C++ code under GCC 8.2 with different options and it always succeeds, produces no warnings and outputs `true`:

```
int && a = 123;
decltype(auto) b = a;

std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<decltype(b), int&>::value;
```

Meanwhile, the same code will not compile in Clang, and if my understanding of the standard is correct, that's the standard-conforming behavior.

cppreference on `decltype`:

> If the argument is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access expression, then decltype yields the type of the entity named by this expression.

cppreference on `decltype(auto)`:

> If the declared type of the variable is decltype(auto), the keyword auto is replaced with the expression (or expression list) of its initializer, and the actual type is deduced using the rules for decltype.

Therefore, `decltype(auto)` should yield `int&&`. And since `a` is an lvalue, it should not bind to `b`, resulting in a compilation error.

So does GCC fail to conform to the standard or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: VS also fails so you're probably right.

Comment: I believe I saw this pointed out in a CppCon slide recently.

Comment: This is reported as [bug #78209](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78209)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your reasoning is sound. And I think I see where GCC is tripping.

The wording for `decltype(auto)` says that `auto` is replaced with the **expression** in the initializer. Which according to GCC would imply your code is not equivalent to

```
decltype(a) b = a;
```

But rather it is equivalent to

```
decltype((a)) b = a;
```

But that is wrong. The initializer *is* *"an unparenthesized id-expression"*, so the rules in [dcl.type.simple] for unparenthesized id-expressions should apply normally. The type of `b` needs to be deduced as `int&&`.

---

And as [@Aconcagua](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1312382/aconcagua) was able to dig up, this is a [known GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64892).

Comment: @Aconcagua - Many thanks. I'm terribly inefficient with GCC's bugzilla.