# Why does decltype(auto) not work as expected?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, decltype, type-deduction

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    auto f1 = [](auto&& e) -> auto
    {
        return e;
    };

    auto f2 = [](auto&& e) -> auto&
    {
        return e;
    };

    auto f3 = [](auto&& e) -> auto&&
    {
        return e;
    };

    auto f4 = [](auto&& e) -> decltype(auto)
    {
        return e;
    };

    int n{};

    f1(std::move(n)); // ok
    f2(std::move(n)); // ok
    f3(std::move(n)); // ok
    f4(std::move(n)); // error
}
```

clang's error message:

> error : rvalue reference to type 'int' cannot bind to lvalue of type 'int'

To me, `decltype(auto)` has only three possible deduced types:

1. `auto`
2. `auto&`
3. `auto&&`

**Why is `f4` error while all of the other three are ok?**

Comment: That error is from Clang. GCC seems to accept it. I'm guessing it's a Clang bug.

Comment: Return type of `decltype(auto)` means that `return e;` causes the return type to be `decltype(e)`, which is `int&&` for `f4`

Comment: @M.M why is `f3` ok while `f4` isn't?

Comment: @xmllmx `auto&&` return type deduces to `int&` in the instantiation invoked by `f3(std::move(n))`, and `e` can initialize `int&`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64892).

`decltype(auto) = e`  is equivalent to `decltype(e)` and yield the declared type of `e`.

`auto` works as template parameter which mean that `auto&&` is the same as `T&&` (forwarding reference) for an invented template parameter.

For **f1** the return type is deduced to `int`.

For **f2** the return type `auto&` is equivalent to `T&` with deduced `T=int` which is the type of the lvalue `e`, here you're binding `int&` to `e`.

For **f3** consider this:

```
auto&& t = n;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(t), int&>); // true
```

for both the return of `f3`, `auto&&` is equivalent to the invented template parameter `T&&` which is a forwarding reference, this initialized with an lvalue, yield `T&` with deduced `T=int`, then again ... binding `int&` to the lvalue `e`.

Now for **f4** consider this:

```
int&& r = 9;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(r), int&&>); // true (1)

decltype(auto) t = r; // fail with the same error you got.
```

the parameter of `f4` is also a forwarding reference `T&&` that is initialized with the xvalue `std::move(n)`, this deduce `T=int` resulting in a parameter `int&& e`. A return type as `decltype(auto)` with `return e` means that the actual return is `decltype(e)`, then as you can see (1) is true, the same hold for `decltype(e)`, this means that the actual return of `f4` is `int&&` ... and there's the problem, `f4` is trying to bind a rvalue `int&&` to an lvalue `e` which is prohibited.

You can also take a look at [@StoryTeller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53358911/1316462) for the GCC bug.

Comment: Should `auto&& t = n;` be `auto&& t = std::move(n);` ?

Comment: It depend on what you want to do ... you should think of these as if you were working with a function template like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18533510abf9cdea)

Comment: What is the deduced return type of `f3`, `int&` or `int&&`?

Comment: @xmllmx `int&` you can check it with `static_assert(std::is_same_v<int&, decltype(f3(std::move(n)))>);`

Comment: @xmllmx Glad I was of help

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64892 - Courtesy of [Aconcagua](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53358911/817643).