# Validity of presenting an xvalue as an lvalue

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, move-semantics, xvalue

The following function (in my intention) is to take an rvalue and present it as it was an lvalue.

```
auto constexpr RtoL = [](auto&& r) -> decltype(auto) {
    static_assert(std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(r)>, "Gimme rvalues, not lvalues.");
    return (r);
};
```

I think of using it in situations where I can guarantee that an xvalue has not been truly moved from (e.g. it was casted to rvalue via `std::move`, but nothing took advantage of that), so I'd call it with xvalues, not prvalues.

Anyway, [compilers (well, versions of GCC) seem to have different opinions on the validity of the code above](https://godbolt.org/z/hq9q5cc6d). Specifically, given this usage:

```cpp
int main() {
    int x{3};
    RtoL(std::move(x));
}
```

GCC 11.2 considers it invalid:

```
<source>:9:14: error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'int&&' to lvalue of type 'int'
    9 |     return (r);
      |              ^
```

whereas GCC 10.3 and other compilers consider it valid.

Furthermore, changing the return statement from

```
return (r);
```

to

```
return static_cast<decltype(r)&>(r);
```

makes them all agree that the code is correct.

Where is the truth, from the standard standpoint?

Comment: Gcc seems to have issue with `decltype(auto)`, returning `int&` works [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/48jK4s4f4) or even `auto&` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Yhq3qff3M).

Comment: Possibly minimal exemplary code with the same issue: `int&& r = 1; decltype(auto) rr = (r);`. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/jWzEadYsW.

Comment: Relevant (possibly duplicate): [GCC's decltype(auto) doesn't conform to the standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53358751/580083).

Comment: @DanielLangr, following the like you posted, I could get [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78209), where I read _fixed in GCC 11_, but the version where I observe the problem is exactly GCC 11.2. Should I deduce that the bug has been reintroduced? Do you suggest filing another report?

Comment: @Enlico I am not a Bugzilla expert, but I guess yes, it seems that the problem has not been fixed as advertized.

Comment: [Reported](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=103403).

Comment: Note that C++23 will [require the cast](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2022/p2266r3.html) (or `*&r`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=103403) in past versions of GCC (located by commenter @Enlico)

The bug is fixed by GCC version 12.2, but still manifests with GCC 11.3. It will likely be fixed in GCC 11.4 as well.

See this on [<kbd>GodBolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/nT87E7Gqs).