# Is the correct return type deduced with decltype(auto)?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, decltype-auto

```
decltype(auto) func(int&& n)
{
    return (n);
}
```

`clang 12.0.1` accepts this code, but `gcc 11.2.1` rejects it with:

```
error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'int&&' to lvalue of type 'int'
```

`gcc` seems to use return type `int &&`, but with `n` inside parenthesis, is that correct?

[godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hedo5Eo6x)

Comment: Curiously GCC 10 (and earlier) accepts that code, and only GCC 11 rejects it. [Demo on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rhcex56eM)

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70092776/validity-of-presenting-an-xvalue-as-an-lvalue

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=103403 It passes on trunk (verifialbe on godbolt)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53358911/1387438

Comment: Fixed on GCC trunk: https://godbolt.org/z/ecEbc1nGz.

Comment: @MarekR That question is about `int && a = 123; decltype(auto) b = a;`, which is correctly rejected by gcc 11

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that `decltype(auto)` shall deduce to `int&` here, and what you have discovered is a [GCC 11 bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=103403) that appears to have been fixed.

As for a long answer, let's examine how placeholder type deduction works for `decltype(auto)` return types:

> A type `T` containing a placeholder type, and a corresponding *initializer-clause* `E`, are determined as follows:
>
> - If the `return` statement has no operand, then `E` is `void()`.
> - If the operand is a *braced-init-list*, the program is ill-formed.
> - If the operand is an expression `X` that is not an [*assignment-expression*](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#nt:assignment-expression), `E` is `(X)`.
>   *[Note 1: A comma expression ([expr.comma]) is not an [*assignment-expression*](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#nt:assignment-expression). - end note]*
> - **Otherwise, `E` is the operand of the return statement.**

- [[dcl.type.auto.deduct] §2](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.auto.deduct#2)

Note that our expression `(n)` is an [*assignment-expression*](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#nt:assignment-expression)<sup>1)</sup>, so the last bullet point applies, meaning `E = (n)`. This is what happens with `E`:

> If the *placeholder-type-specifier* is of the form *type-constraint*<sub>opt</sub> `decltype(auto)`, `T` shall be the placeholder alone.
> The type deduced for `T` is determined as described in [[dcl.type.decltype]](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype), as though `E` had been the operand of the `decltype`.

- [[dcl.type.auto.deduct] §4](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.auto.deduct#4)

This means that the return type `T` is deduced as if by:

```cpp
using T = decltype(E); // E = (n)
```

To determine what type `decltype(E)` denotes:

> For an expression `E`, the type denoted by `decltype(E)` is defined as follows:
>
> - if `E` is an unparenthesized [...]
> - otherwise, if `E` is an xvalue, `decltype(E)` is `T&&`, where `T` is the type of `E`;
> - **otherwise, if `E` is an lvalue, `decltype(E)` is `T&`, where `T` is the type of `E`;**
> - otherwise, `decltype(E)` is the type of `E`.

- [[dcl.type.decltype] §1](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype#1)

`n` is an [*unqualified-id*](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.unqual#nt:unqualified-id) which is an lvalue, and so is `(n)`. Therefore, the second bullet point applies and `decltype(auto)` deduces to `int&`.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Contrary to the name, [*assignment-expression*](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#nt:assignment-expression)s not only include assignments. If we follow the the grammatical rules deep enough, we eventually arrive at [*primary-expression*](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#nt:primary-expression), which includes [*id-expression*](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#nt:id-expression) and parenthesization.